# Write to SD card "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied"

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, storage-access-framework

There are many similar questions here on stackoverflow, but I still couldn't find a solution to my particular problem:

I have an app with the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and a non-exported file provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.cgogolin.library"
      ...
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
      ...
      <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.cgogolin.library.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
      </provider>
</application>
```

which is further specified in `provider_paths.xml` as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
  <root-path name="external_files2" path="/storage/"/>
</paths>
```

and which I want to use to serve files from the sdcard to other apps (My app acts more or less as a file browser in this case, but not quite...).

As I am using API level 23 I also dynamically request the permissions by calling

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
```

The dialog window is shown, and after I click "Allow" (and restart the app due to the bug described in [Can't write to external storage unless app is restarted after granting permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062006/cant-write-to-external-storage-unless-app-is-restarted-after-granting-permissio)) the App correctly obtains the permissions, which I can verified by testing whether

```
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

and it is indeed true. I can also obtain a `Uri` to a `File` file from the sdcard with something like

```
Uri uri = android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.cgogolin.library.fileprovider", file);
```

I can read from that file and I can for example successfully start an `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` to open the file in an external App.

But: Despite having write permissions, I can not write to the file. All attempts to open an `OutputStream` or `ParcelFileDescriptor` to `uri` with either of the following

```
context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri, "wa");
context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "wa");
```

either directly from my App or from an App opened via `Intent` result in a

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
```

Where is my mistake? I thought that after `checkSelfPermission()` tells me I have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` I should actually be able to do so.

Comment: Everything seems correct. Please can you connect phone to computer and try to create a file to the folder you work. Write result here.

Comment: How exactly do you want me to create a file? From within my App? Via adb?

Comment: Not with adb. With file manager.

Comment: I can do that without problems. For example, if I chose a file on the sdcard with the default `Files` App and open it with the exact same app to which I send the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` in the above example, I can overwrite the file or save to a new file in the same directory. The same is possible if I open a file on the sdcard from that latter App with a `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: As per your question, I want to use to serve files from the sdcard to other apps (My app acts more or less as a file browser in this case, but not quite...). if you are accessing other apps private directories than its not permuted by Android OS, because its follows Linux file system.

Comment: The problem occurs for files in a generic directory called `dir` in the root of the scdard.

Comment: You cannot serve files from SD card using a FileProvider. But it is unclear to me if you really use files from SD card. Please tell full paths so we can check.

Comment: A sample path of the `File file` in the above example would be `/storage/0000-0000/dir/file1.pdf`.

Comment: That looks like SD card. But 0000-0000? Strange. But anyhow FileProvider is useless.

Answer (score 0):

> and which I want to use to serve files from the sdcard to other apps

First, there is no documented `root-path` on `FileProvider`.

Second, you have no read or write access to removable storage, outside of very specific locations (e.g., 2nd and subsequent values returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`). The external storage permissions have nothing to do with removable storage.

Comment: Well, I definitely have read access. I thought writing was solved with the new `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission that has to be dynamically requested? There surely is a way to achieve this. With SolidExplorer I can, for example write to all directories on my sdcard.

Comment: Yes you will allways have read access. But the card is readonly nowadays. And you can write to all directories too if you use Storage Access Framework instead of File and FileOutputStream classes.

Comment: Not to Apps like SolidExplorer, they can write even without root. So if not with the method above, how do such Apps achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to let the user give the App write permissions via a `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` for the whole sdcard (or the relevant subdirectory) as suggested also in this post [Android SD Card Write Permission using SAF (Storage Access Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862675/android-sd-card-write-permission-using-saf-storage-access-framework).