# Why does my app sometimes restart after a crash?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

Faced with the following problem - my application restarts after a crash. This does not happen on all activities (activities with fragments located on them are used for navigation).

The following happens - when an exception is made, the application is restarted, all running activities are also recreated (similar to when the permission is revoked in the application settings). If you get an exception again on the same screen after that, the application will crash normally - with the dialog showing, the application closing, etc.

The behavior is similar to [Why would Application sometimes restart on killProcess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726100/why-would-application-sometimes-restart-on-killprocess) however, my application does not use killProcess().

Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler is also not used. There is no explicit restart implementation in my application.

Unfortunately I won't be able to show the application code

Please tell me what could be the reason for this behavior? How can I prevent the app from being re-created after a crash?

I tried using Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler with killProcess() and ExitProcess() - it didn't bring any result

I looked at the code of the activities used, I did not find any significant differences

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you see anything in the logcat when the app crashes? Have a look at the logs this might give important information. Be sure not to filter the logcat because you might miss something important.